# Binary outcome with categorical predictors - experiment control

Tags: regression, optimization, binomial-distribution

I have a problem which I try to formalize/decompose/map to well-known cases, so this is more of a call for references/names/terms.

Description of the problem:

The system receives a stream of plant seeds, each seed having a few categorical properties. For each seed, the system chooses a cultivation protocol to use (thus adding a few more categorical properties). As a result of cultivation, a seed may eventually bring a single fruit (but more likely will never bring any). The ultimate goal of the system is to maximize the number of fruits.

End of description.

Ideally, I would like a pointer to literature concerned with a similar problem (not necessarily about plants, may be formulated for manufacture similarly). I recognize, though, that the problem is a complex one, and it is more likely to find prior art for separate pieces of it.

There are also some simplifications I am willing to allow. E.g., instead of any seed being in either "fruit is obtained" or "fruit is not yet obtained but potentially may be" states, it can be stated as being in either "fruit is obtained" or "fruit is not obtained and never will be", thus reducing cultivation of every seed to a Bernoulli trial. Let's call the probability of getting a (single) fruit "fecundity" (though this is different from the usual meaning in biology).

One of the possible decompositions I see is reducing the goal of maximizing total number of fruits to density estimation of fecundity (indexed by all possible combinations of properties of both seed and its cultivation protocol). This does not answer how to combine exploration with exploitation, but I hope to use the multi-armed bandit analysis for that.

An extremely simplified example would be 2 properties for seeds: color (red, black, white), pattern (striped, solid, spotted) and 1 property for cultivation: soil (sandy, mud, hydroponic). Upon seeing a red striped seed the system could decide to plant it into sandy soil, for example (or maybe to plant it into sandy soil 60% of cases, and 40% into mud).
In real problem the number of properties is ~ 6-7, and some of them have hundreds/thousands of values (e.g., source farm). This is already bad, but in addition, fecundity is very low (~1 fruit per 10 thousand seeds), so even with millions of experiments, the coincidence matrix of property values is going to be quite sparse - thus I am not optimistic about using linear logistic regression. I think the only way to arrive to any estimates of fecundity for most of combinations of seed/cultivation properties is by utilizing dependency among fecundity for "similar" combinations - by similar here I mean the ones sharing at least one property value. Empirically, existence of such dependency is confirmed, but its specific nature is unknown - e.g., fecundity of seeds of the same color on different cultivation protocols more closely correlates to each other than to fecundity of random seeds; and the same is true for seeds of the same pattern, but it is not clear how to model this (hierarchical Bayesian generative model?).

At the moment I am looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_sampling, with a context corresponding to a seed, and an action corresponding to a cultivation protocol, but the main missing piece is the specific model of distributions.

Any ideas or even questions are appreciated!

Comment: "Estimating Rates of Rare Events with Multiple Hierarchies
through Scalable Log-linear Models" looks promising.
[link](http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~lzhen001/activities/KDD_USB.../p213.pdf)